# error using androids drag and drop API - "Error inflating class Android.widget.ImageButton"

Tags: android, xml, drag-and-drop, resources

I am trying to use Androids drag and drop feature as outlined here: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/try-androids-useful-drag-and-drop-api/

Four balls are to be made to be drag and droppable between top and bottom container.
For the first three it works fine. Adding a fourth yellow ball makes the app crash. 
I am very confused, as I don't see anything different in how I treat the fourth ball.
Taking away one of the earlier balls, and replacing it with the new ball gives the same
error. Really happy for any ideas! I'm using eclipse.

Instead of "red_ball.xml" as outlined in the above link, these files look like this:

```
   <View xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ball_yellow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src = "@drawable/ball_8"
    />
    </View>
```

with different values of id and src for each ball.

The "activity_main.xml" file in the link above looks like this in my program, and is called "startscreen.xml":

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/green_bumped_mandelbrot_blackhole"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:weightSum="6"
        tools:context=".StartScreen" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/containertop"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/ball_red"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:onClick="playSound"
                    android:src="@drawable/ball_4" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/ball_blue"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:onClick="playSound"
                    android:src="@drawable/ball_6" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/ball_green"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:onClick="playSound"
                    android:src="@drawable/ball_7" />
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/ball_yellow"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:onClick="playSound"
                    android:src="@drawable/ball_8"/>

            </LinearLayout>



            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/containerbottom"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/teleporter"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:onClick="loadOtherDimension"
                    android:src="@drawable/teleport_button" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/black_hole"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.6"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:src="@drawable/blank_square" >
                </LinearLayout>

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/square_red"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:onClick="playSound"
                    android:src="@drawable/blank_square" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

The xml files are used in this way:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        setContentView(R.layout.startscreen);
        findViewById(R.id.ball_red).setOnTouchListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.ball_blue).setOnTouchListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.ball_green).setOnTouchListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.ball_yellow).setOnTouchListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.containertop).setOnDragListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.black_hole).setOnDragListener(this);
```

I get this error output:

```
:44:15.647: E/AndroidRuntime(18105): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-22 22:44:15.647: E/AndroidRuntime(18105): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gnyrfta.fallingobjects/com.gnyrfta.fallingobjects.StartScreen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageButton
04-22 22:44:15.647: E/AndroidRuntime(18105):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
04-22 22:44:15.647: E/AndroidRuntime(18105):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
04-22 22:44:15.647: E/AndroidRuntime(18105):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
04-22 22:44:15.647: E/AndroidRuntime(18105):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
04-22 22:44:15.647: E/AndroidRuntime(18105):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-22 22:44:15.647: E/AndroidRuntime(18105):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-22 22:44:15.647: E/AndroidRuntime(18105):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
04-22 22:44:15.647: E/AndroidRuntime(18105):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-22 22:44:15.647: E/AndroidRuntime(18105):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-22 22:44:15.647: E/AndroidRuntime(18105):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
04-22 22:44:15.647: E/AndroidRuntime(18105):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
04-22 22:44:15.647: E/AndroidRuntime(18105):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-22 22:44:15.647: E/AndroidRuntime(18105): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageButton
04-22 22:44:15.647: E/AndroidRuntime(18105):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
04-22 22:44:15.647: E/AndroidRuntime(18105):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
04-22 22:44:15.647: E/AndroidRuntime(18105):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:666)
04-22 22:44:15.647: E/AndroidRuntime(18105):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
04-22 22:44:15.647: E/AndroidRuntime(18105):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
04-22 22:44:15.647: E/AndroidRuntime(18105):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:760)
04-22 22:44:15.647: E/AndroidRuntime(18105):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:760)
04-22 22:44:15.647: E/AndroidRuntime(18105):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
04-22 22:44:15.647: E/AndroidRuntime(18105):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
04-22 22:44:15.647: E/AndroidRuntime(18105):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
04-22 22:44:15.647: E/AndroidRuntime(18105):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:316)
04-22 22:44:15.647: E/AndroidRuntime(18105):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1924)
04-22 22:44:15.647: E/AndroidRuntime(18105):    at com.gnyrfta.fallingobjects.StartScreen.onCreate(StartScreen.java:111)
04-22 22:44:15.647: E/AndroidRuntime(18105):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
04-22 22:44:15.647: E/AndroidRuntime(18105):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
04-22 22:44:15.647: E/AndroidRuntime(18105):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
04-22 22:44:15.647: E/AndroidRuntime(18105):    ... 11 more
04-22 22:44:15.647: E/AndroidRuntime(18105): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-22 22:44:15.647: E/AndroidRuntime(18105):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
04-22 22:44:15.647: E/AndroidRuntime(18105):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
04-22 22:44:15.647: E/AndroidRuntime(18105):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:593)
04-22 22:44:15.647: E/AndroidRuntime(18105):    ... 26 more
04-22 22:44:15.647: E/AndroidRuntime(18105): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ball_4.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020007
04-22 22:44:15.647: E/AndroidRuntime(18105):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2265)
04-22 22:44:15.647: E/AndroidRuntime(18105):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
04-22 22:44:15.647: E/AndroidRuntime(18105):    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:126)
04-22 22:44:15.647: E/AndroidRuntime(18105):    at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:87)
04-22 22:44:15.647: E/AndroidRuntime(18105):    at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:83)
04-22 22:44:15.647: E/AndroidRuntime(18105):    ... 29 more
04-22 22:44:15.647: E/AndroidRuntime(18105): Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #1: invalid drawable tag View
04-22 22:44:15.647: E/AndroidRuntime(18105):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:913)
04-22 22:44:15.647: E/AndroidRuntime(18105):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:854)
04-22 22:44:15.647: E/AndroidRuntime(18105):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2262)
04-22 22:44:15.647: E/AndroidRuntime(18105):    ... 33 more
```

Comment: Are you really trying to put **an ImageView inside a View**?!!!!!!

Comment: Thanks for checking it out Bob. I took away the extra layer of view, and used an ImageView directly. But this does not change the behaviour of the app. It crashes as long as i add a new xml file to

Comment: It seems that you assigned different objects (ImageViews and ImageButtons) the very same id... which is wrong `Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageButton`. Also check this line: `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ball_4.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020007` which says that ball_4.xml is not found in drawable

Comment: It works now! I just have to figure out why... I added a file called ball_5.xml to the sources folder instead of ball_4.xml. Thanks, good to know its wrong to assign the same id to an imagebutton and an ImageView, even when they are containing same object. Makes sense. But it works to do, eventhough I get its not good programming.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51290/discussion-between-gnyrfta-and-bob-malooga)

Answer (score 0):

It works now! I just have to figure out why... I added a file called ball_5.xml to the sources folder instead of ball_4.xml. If I figure out why this makes a difference I'll post it.